# Filter an array of objects based on field name

Tags: swift, filter, higher-order-functions

Consider an object, `Notification`, with the following properties:

```
id: String
body: String
repeats: Bool
```

and consider an array of `Notification`s, `notifications`:

```
let notifications = [Notification(id: "1", body: "body1", repeats: false),
                     Notification(id: "2", body: "body2", repeats: false),
                     Notification(id: "3", body: "body3", repeats: true)]
```

How can I use the higher-order `filter()` function to retrieve an array of *Strings* corresponding to each `id`?

In other words, I would like to write a `filter()` closure to which I pass my `notifications` and the resulting output is:

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

Therefore, my filter comparison operator should be based on the property name. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` is not the appropriate tool here. `filter` would be for returning a subset of the notifications based on some criteria (such as only repeating notifications, for example).

You want `map` which is used to transform data.

```
let idList = notifications.map { $0.id }
```

You can combine these as needed. Let's say you wanted the list of ids for the repeating notifications.

```
let ids = notifications.filter { $0.repeats }.map { $0.id }
```